# Best Practises in Android Resources Naming

Tags: android, resources, naming

There are a lot of android resources types: layouts, strings, drawables and so on. I understand that readability of it's names is important but can not create a table of rules how to name them in the best way.

Are there any best practices on that?

Comment: I don't think this is a particularly constructive question. I'll monitor the answers to see if anything useful comes out, but it's likely to be closed fairly soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never came accross an "official" good practice for naming resource. Each type of resource is kinda located in a specific directory (layouts in "res/layout", etc., so I think common sense is enough here.

Answer (score -1):

I think a good practice is to name the resources uniting the  the activity name (if exists), object type or object name, and property name, using all chars in lower case. I believe that if the resources exists, it'll be used, so I would name my resources like below:

If I have a object used in a Activity:

mainactivity_button_id - using the type of object
mainactivity_button_ok_id - using the name of object

If the object isn't been used in a Activity or is used in various locals:

global_string_messagetext